# Infinite union of closed sets $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define $A_n = [2^{1-n},2^n]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is the set $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ equal to $(0,\infty)$ or $[0,\infty)$.

As $2^{1-n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and we define $A_n$ with closed brackets, I feel like the answer should be $(0,\infty)$ but I am not sure about this. What is $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ actually equal to?

Comment: $0\notin A_n$ in your limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0$ were in fact in the union, then it must belong to at least one of its terms, say the $k$th one. This says that $0$ belongs to $[2^{1-k},2^k]$, which is false.  Hence $0$ is not in the union.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):0\notin A_n$, $0\notin\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$.

Comment: No. Not *at all*.